# Is there an itemcontainergenerator.status property in winrt?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to highlight the playing song from a listview, and running into some trouble.  Often, lvicurrent is null.  Here is my code...

```
    private void highlightItem(String focused)
    {
        //songlistView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged????;


        ListViewItem lvicurrent = new ListViewItem();

        if (lviPrevious != null)
        {
            lviPrevious.Background = new SolidColorBrush();
        }

        if (focused.Equals("songListview"))
        {
            lvicurrent = songlistView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(songIndex) as ListViewItem;
            lviPrevious = lvicurrent;
            lvicurrent.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
        }
        else if (focused.Equals("playListview"))
        {
            lvicurrent = playlistView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(songIndex) as ListViewItem;
            lviPrevious = lvicurrent;
            lvicurrent.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
        }
    }

    private void StatusChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Only thing I could find on the internet is wait for the status to be finished, but there is no status property in winrt as far as I can tell.

My other problem is that more than 1 song is being displayed in green. I don't know why this is, maybe because it's a virtualizing stackpanel... but then one would think it would not affect songs not currently visible in the stackpanel. This is the very last thing I need to fix before I publish the app.

Comment: This seems to be a bad way to do things, I'm using a class inherited from StyleSelector now, almost got it working

Answer (score 0):

If ItemConatinerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex() returns null, it does mean that the container at that index has not been generated yet (i.e. the container for the item is still virtualized).

If you have a short collection, you could probably get away with using StackPanel as your ListView's ItemsPanel instead of VirtualizingStackPanel (the default).  With StackPanel, the containers will not be virtualized.  If you have a longer collection, virtualizing is going to be better for your app's performance.

It seems like your scenario requires you to "highlight" a container for a certain item index.  StyleSelector sounds promising if you are adding a "highlight" effect.  You could also probably achieve this by subclassing ListView/ListViewItem.  Have you considered repurposing the notion of selection for your scenario?  ListView inherits from Selector and supports a few SelectionModes.  You could use the Selection visual states for your "highlight" effect.